# Full Page Width Rules From Within Nested Containers

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, containers

I've just had a last-minute design change for a site (IE9+) that is basically done. Without going into too much detail, most of the site lives within stacked containers which have a max-width and are centred using the trusty `margin 0 auto` approach. The site is responsive, and the content rearranges itself into numerous different configurations across screen-sizes and is comprised of a mix of custom layouts and sections that are gallery-like (that have multiple media items arranged in a multicolumn grid).

The new designs add a series of full-page (full bleed) horizontal rules that run across the page between sections and between gallery rows. Obviously given that the site is 1. contained within a series of containers with max-widths and 2. responsive, this is problematic. I don't want to have to redo the layout to accommodate what is essentially a decoration, and given the varying layout, I'm not convinced this would even be possible without lots of extra markup and gymnastics.

After trying to solve this in a variety of ways, my best attempt is use a pseudo class on a section that needs a rule:

```
  ::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc( (-100vw + 100%) * 0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
```

This works reasonably well, but when the element is not both centered and 100% width, this is no good as the rule will be lopsided. Creating different sets of values for different layouts quickly becomes problematic. It also plays badly with scrollbars thanks to some very questionable decisions related to viewport units and scrollbars in the spec (essentially `100vw` is 100% of the window *not allowing for the scrollbar*. This means that as soon as an inline (as opposed to overlaid) scrollbar appears, the rules overflow by the width of the scrollbar.

A nice solution would have been to just absolutely positioned a pseudo element with left and right set to 0, but I cannot guarantee that the body will be the first use of a position other than `static` while working back up the DOM from the point of use.

Given that using a width that extends past the edges of the viewport causes issues with horizontal scrolling that can't be fixed by setting `overflow-x: hidden` on `body` or `html`, are there any other approaches or am I going to have to go down the JavaScript route?

Comment: Does this help? - http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Comment: @Paulie_D Those might be useful in some situations, but due to quirks with the way overflow works, none are viable on my site as they extend far beyond the edges of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Way late, no doubt, but I was thinking `box-shadow` might help with this, as it doesn't force overflow:
http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/NPrQJY

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}

.container {width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; height: 800px; background: #f7f7f7; }

.line {position: relative;}

.small {width: 50%;}

.container > div {background: #e7e7e7; height: 200px; margin: 20px 0;}

.line::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 100vw;
    right: 100%;
    height:2px;
    background:red;
    box-shadow: 100vw 0 red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line small"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I had a bit of a play with it and it's doable with `transform` (although, like calc and/or vw I'm not sure it will play well on IE9).

Anyhow, fwiw here's my attempt. Works great on Mac, but stinky IE11 seemed to need `overflow-x: hidden` on the body to prevent a horizontal scroll, though not sure why).

http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/ogxdgg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {overflow-x: hidden;}

.container {width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; height: 800px; background: #f7f7f7; }

.line {position: relative;}

.container > div {background: #e7e7e7; height: 200px; margin: 20px 0;}

.line::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    right:0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width:100vw;
    height:2px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    transform:translate(-50%, 0);
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing how this improves on what I already have using a pseudo class.

Comment: OK, perhaps I wasn't understanding the situation properly. Regarding your comment `Given that using a width that extends past the edges of the viewport causes issues with horizontal scrolling that can't be fixed by setting overflow-x: hidden on body or html` ... it seems to work well if you place it on *both*. So just make the pseudo elements exceedingly wide with negative left and right values and use html, body {overflow-x: hidden;} and all should be well.

Comment: The problem I have comes in the form of a sticky footer. For this to work I need 100% height on each containing element from html down to the container that wraps the page content. As soon as I set `overflow-x: hidden` on an element, this causes (thanks to ridiculously poorly designed specs), the element's `overflow-y` property to switch from `visible` to `auto`, giving me scrollbars where I don't want them. This means I cannot use `overflow-x:hidden` on these elements, which in turn means I can't allow content to trigger any horizontal overflow at all.